# MapQuest, Leaflet - disable marker on directions layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, markers, mapquest

Is there a way to hide markers generated at directions layer ? I'd like to draw only route.
Or is there a way to set custom icon instead of build ones ?

According to docs:

https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/mapquest-js/v1.3/l-mapquest-directions-layer/

I can only change style of start-marker / end-marker, but I don't want it at all.

Or maybe there is a way to extend directionLayer, and somehow override markers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was my first question at SO, a this is my first answer :)

```
var icoEmpty = L.icon({iconUrl: 'a'});

var directions = L.mapquest.directions();
directions.route({
  start: 'San Francisco, CA',
  waypoints: ['Palo Alto, CA'],
  end: 'San Jose, CA'
}, createMap);

var DirectionsLayerWithEmptyMarkers = L.mapquest.DirectionsLayer.extend({
    createStartMarker: function(location, stopNumber) {return L.marker(location.latLng, {icon: icoEmpty});},
    createWaypointMarker: function(location, stopNumber) {return L.marker(location.latLng, {icon: icoEmpty});},
    createEndMarker: function(location, stopNumber) {return L.marker(location.latLng, {icon: icoEmpty});},
  });

function createMap(err, response) {
  var directionsLayer = new DirectionsLayerWithEmptyMarkers({
    directionsResponse: response
  }).addTo(map);
}
```